# Radix Sort: A C++ version

Tags: c++, sorting, radix-sort

Just realized I have never implemented Radix Sort (spurred about watching a YouTube video about it). So I thought I would give it a go.

This is Radix Sort, using a counting implementation. For numbers that are `N` bytes in length, we use an `N` pass counting approach. Starting with the least significant byte we do a counting sort of all the values. We then repeat the counting sort using each consecutively higher byte in the values as the index.

Only have access to C++17 (so added some view objects (that I believe are available in C++20).

Comment on anything appreciated.

Suggestions on how I could remove the final `std::move()` to remove that copy would be nice. If I was not using iterators, that would be trivial. I am sure I can do it with some thought.

#### Views

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>


// A normal and reverse view created from Iterators.
// Makes using the Range based `for()` easier rather than having
// to manually work with the iterators themselves.
template<typename I>
struct View
{
    I beginRange;
    I endRange;
    View(I beginRange, I endRange)
        : beginRange(beginRange)
        , endRange(endRange)
    {}
    using iterator = I;
    iterator begin() {return beginRange;}
    iterator end()   {return endRange;}
};
template<typename I>
struct ReverseView
{
    I beginRange;
    I endRange;
    ReverseView(I beginRange, I endRange)
        : beginRange(beginRange)
        , endRange(endRange)
    {}
    using iterator = std::reverse_iterator<I>;
    iterator begin() {return iterator(endRange);}
    iterator end()   {return iterator(beginRange);}
};
```

#### Radix Sort

```
template<typename I>
void rsort(I begin, I end)
{
    // Create an intermediate output container.
    using Type = typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type;
    std::vector<Type>               output(std::distance(begin, end));

    // A loop to loop over each byte as the radix index.
    for (int index = 0; index < sizeof(Type); ++index) {

        // Keep track of counts for each radix value.
        // Since we are using bytes we need 256 values 0->255
        std::array<std::uint64_t, 0x100>  count{};

        // Step 1: Count each radix value.
        // Complexity O(n)
        for (auto const& value: View(begin, end)) {
            ++count[  (value >> (index * 8)) & 0xFF ];
        }

        // Step 2: Calculate prefix value.
        // Effectively if we do a count sort this is the
        // one past the end of the range for this value
        // of radix to be stored.
        // Complexity O(1)   assuming 255 is small compared to n
        std::uint64_t sum = 0;
        for (auto& c: count) {
            sum = sum + c;
            c = sum;
        }

        // Step 3: Copy from the input to output by
        // using the radex index (do in reverse order).
        // Complexity O(n)
        for (auto const& value: ReverseView(begin, end)) {

            // Offset starts at one past the end of the
            // range for this radix value.
            std::uint64_t&  offset = count[ (value >> (index * 8)) & 0xFF ];

            // So subtract one before using.
            // It now becomes one past the end for the remaining
            // values in the input array for this count.
            --offset;
            output[offset] = value;
        }

        // Step 4: Copy output back to the input.
        //         I am sure I can eliminate this step with some thought.
        // Complexity O(n)
        std::move(std::begin(output), std::end(output), begin);
    }
}
```

So Complexity is `O(4 * (3n + 1))` => `O(12n + 4)` => `O(n)`.

#### A test harness:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data{4583,182,5433,8092,11465,6614,29731,24061,29432,24542,32685,9724,31005,456,29255,25325,30048,18875,27775,30360,13531,1029,5715,3729,31680,22998,2359,29525,15433,7106,20196,11561,20578,14325,231,6835,8729,22579,21733,21845,28353,25495,8623,32589,4329,24583,10505,22413,32000,28538,12858,12123,23749,25833,16723,7593,30064,11542,30528,3122,17570,1792,26256,31321,13,18465,26884,4544,25571,10349,16857,26795,31744,21003,6357,3603,21462,12498,6675,15242,14620,15746,18063,18642,32054,16583,16753,15675,24931,18926};

    rsort(std::begin(data), std::end(data));
    std::cout << "[ ";
    char sep = ' ';
    for (auto const& v: data) {
        std::cout << sep << " " << v;
        sep = ',';
    }
    std::cout << " ]\n";
}
```

The result:

```
[   13, 182, 231, 456, 1029, 1792, 2359, 3122, 3603, 3729, 4329, 4544, 4583, 5433, 5715, 6357, 6614, 6675, 6835, 7106, 7593, 8092, 8623, 8729, 9724, 10349, 10505, 11465, 11542, 11561, 12123, 12498, 12858, 13531, 14325, 14620, 15242, 15433, 15675, 15746, 16583, 16723, 16753, 16857, 17570, 18063, 18465, 18642, 18875, 18926, 20196, 20578, 21003, 21462, 21733, 21845, 22413, 22579, 22998, 23749, 24061, 24542, 24583, 24931, 25325, 25495, 25571, 25833, 26256, 26795, 26884, 27775, 28353, 28538, 29255, 29432, 29525, 29731, 30048, 30064, 30360, 30528, 31005, 31321, 31680, 31744, 32000, 32054, 32589, 32685 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

First, it's good to see someone use iterator pairs and (somewhat) generic code, as opposed to the usual hard-coded collections being passed.

---

Your `View` templates define constructors which don't do anything that would not be automatic had you left that out.  Having common data members for more than one class suggests you can use a common base class for the data, to propagate the convention.
(Given only these two views, you could use a single template template argument to specify the Iterator type and only need to write it once).

---

Step 2:  There's a standard algorithm for that already.  You don't need to write that loop.

---

`(value >> (index * 8)) & 0xFF` is written more than once.  How the key byte is extracted should be abstracted.  I'm surprised to see it written this way, as opposed to viewing the value as an array of `std::byte`.  This only works for value types that are integers.

---

Generally, a function that has "steps" should actually be separate functions.

---

You have one test case?  You can generate random collections of different sizes and test the result of your function call with `is_sorted`, or a call to the standard library sort.  With the latter you also have the opportunity to compare the speeds.  If you test different container types as well, you might find that your algorithm is faster when you don't have efficient random-access iterators for the collection being sorted.  But `std::list` is only forward iterating and you need bidirectional iterators.

With your one single test case, you don't need to make it a `vector` but could use a plain array.

Comment: Never a plain array ....... aahhhhhh. The pain of using C types.

Comment: @MartinYork you can use `std::array` if you prefer, even though it's not needed for simple local data that will be iterated over and not passed or returned in whole.  It doesn't let you omit the size parameter though, so you have to use a further work-around of make_array, which is less elegant.  Personally, thanks to non-member `begin` etc. the issues with built-in array types are largely gone.  It's only a thing if you want to pass the entire array to a non-template (why??) or return an array.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to JDługosz's answer:

## Use `std::size_t`

Use it for `index`, as the value type of the array `count`, for `sum` and `index`. Using it for `index` avoids the comparison between signed and unsigned values, and since you can never count more elements than a `std::size_t` can hold, it's the perfect type for `count`. In fact, it will be more efficient that way on 32-bit architectures.

## Use `+=` where appropriate

Instead of `sum = sum + c`, write `sum += c` instead.

## Consider making `rsort()` take a `View` as the argument

Especially if the caller already uses `View`s themselves, it would be nice to be able to pass that to `rsort()` instead of having to manually specify the begin and end iterator. There are several ways to do this and still allow separate begin/end iterators to be used by the caller. One is to just add an overload, the second way is to only have a version that takes a `View`:

```
template<typename I>
void rsort(View<I> view) {
    ...
}
```

And the caller can then still do something like:

```
std::vector<int> data{4583, 182, 5433, ...};
rsort({std::begin(data), std::end(data)});
```

This requires extra curly braces though. Another way is to add a copy constructor to `View`, and make `rsort()` take a parameter pack that is perfectly forwarded to the constructor of `View`:

```
template<typename I>
struct View
{
    View(const View &other) = default;

    View(I beginRange, I endRange)
        : beginRange(beginRange)
        , endRange(endRange)
    {}
    ...
};

template<typename... Args>
void rsort(Args&&... args) {
    View view(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    ...
}
```

Of course now you have the problem that error messages due to incorrect arguments are not so nice, unless you add concepts.

## Avoid step 4

There are several possible [in-place radix sort algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Specialized_variants) that you could try to implement. There are also people who submitted their in-place radix sort to Code Review, like [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23999/stable-radix-sort-in-place-using-o1-space), that you can have a look at.